# level curves of vector valued functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

It's possible that I've used the wrong term, but I have a function $f(\vec{x}) = \vec{y}$ with $\vec{x} \in R^n$ and $\vec{y} \in R^m$.  Is there a way to find (or approximate) the vectors $\vec{x}_o$ such that $\vec{y} = \vec{0}$?  In particular, I'd like functions of the components of $x$, or at least some way to approximate them... I don't think this is quite the same as finding a level curve, but it sounds like there are some similarities...

I know that in general finding the zeros of a nonlinear function is an impossible task, but I'm not quite sure what to look for in terms of approximating the zeros, and in particular it's a bit more complicated because the function I'm looking at has continuous curves in which the value is zero.

Comment: the terminology is "inverse image" as in your $f^{-1}(\vec{0}).$ If all the component functions of $f$ are polynomials, the result is called a variety, and studied in algebraic geometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is equivalent to the following: you have $m$ function $f_i: {\mathbb R}^n \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$, $i=1,2,3,...,m$ and you would like to find the intersection $\cap_{i=1}^n \{ x\in {\mathbb R}^n : f_i(x) = 0 \}$ This will in general be an $n-m$ dimensional surface in ${\mathbb R}^n$ and even for $m=1$ it will be a challenge to compute / understand it. If $f_i$ are polynomials then it will be an algebraic variety. The following may be a useful starting point http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/geometry-and-topology/first-course-computational-algebraic-geometry